# Encoding categorical variables : TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python

I tried to encode my categorical variables via the LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder method.
My X matrix is ​​composing of variables all with floats and my Y with variables of type object:

```
X = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == np.float64]
Y = df['VCat']
```

when I apply my method:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
Y = labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(Y)
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
Y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(Y).toarray()
```

out :

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some missing data in your dataframe. Treat the missing data before performing this action.

You can use df.count() to check which columns have the missing data.

If that doesn't work, go through your data and make sure that each column contains only data of the type that it is trying to parse

Comment: Ok, I think I have other problems in the data before dealing with my missing values.